# SQL(ite) fast retrieval of multiple substrings of larger string (genome)

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, bioinformatics

I have a sql database consisting of a genome, its chromosomes, and "*interesting*" regions (in BED format). A genome (e.g. 4GB) consists of +/- 20 chromosomes, so each string is around 200MB large. The chromosome in a genome for instance consists of the string:

```
NNNNATCCAGGAGAATTACAT...ACCGGGAATTCCCGGNNNNN # 200 MB large
```

Let's say I have around 1.000.000 regions ATAC-seq peaks and I would like to get the sequences of 100 bp of only chromosome 3. My SQL query would look like this:

```
SELECT substr(Chr.Sequence, Bed.ChromStart + Bed.Peak - 50, 100) FROM Bed Bed
INNER JOIN Chromosome Chr ON Bed.ChromosomeId = Chr.ChromosomeId
WHERE Chr.Chromosome = 'chr3'
```

The problem with these kind of lookups is that the `Chr.Sequence` is loaded for every single hit, making the ram usage excessively large, and the lookup really slow. The way I 'fixed' this is only using the SQL database to store the positions of the interesting locations, and then using `pyfaidx` to quickly get the corresponding sequences out of the chromosome.

I am wondering if a fast lookup is possible in SQL(ite), since the current solution feels a bit ad-hoc to me.

Comment: the index concept is something that might help in this type of cases.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  You describe some things about genes, but then have a table called `bed` in the query.  You are using `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` clause and no `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry about that, I changed the query. I was a bit overzealous with simplifying it. BED is a very common data structure in bioinformatics. My idea was to give a bit of background about what data we are working with, but apparently only made it less clear. Btw I never mention genes.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to optimize the query or the storage? If it is the only way you ever use the sequences, maybe you could keep them in chunks?

Comment: @Mafor Preferably the query. The current bottleneck seems to be that for every hit the same chr.sequence is read from disk and loaded in ram. I am hoping some "smarter" substr call exists which skips the independent loading of the chr.sequence.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande And how big are the substrings? Always ~100?

Comment: @Mafor No, they might range between 100-50.000. I am not entirely unhappy with the solution of using SQL to get all the positions (chromstart) and using another tool to get the strings that belong to it. I am relatively new to SQL and was wondering if a pure SQL solution for this exists.

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Sande, maybe I'm too far from bioinformatics, but your explanation don't really help :). Example of input tables and expected output table would be more useful.

Comment: If you're only concerned with the query, then you can look at running explain query plan and analyzing the results: https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: A full SQL server application (like Postgres, for example) would most likely automatically optimize the loading behavior and you shouldn't have to worry about that. Use explain to see what is handled how during query execution.

Comment: If you only want to analyse bed files using bgzip and tabix `$ bgzip example_sort.bed
$ tabix -p bed example_sort.bed.gz` bed file with https://pypi.org/project/pybedtools/ should be sufficient for your problem.

Comment: I don't believe there is a good way to do this in SQL. An index won't help. Indexes are for quickly finding rows, your problem seems to be about efficiently scanning a particular value extracted from a column. I believe most SQL databases will try to bring the value into memory when you select it (there may be exceptions I'm not aware of). I'm missing some detail about the input/output and BED table, but I believe your fastest approach is going to be some form of linear time scanning through the string and looking for your pattern(s). It sounds like you ended up doing that in some form.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was already expecting something like what @totalhack describes, but it's nice (I guess) to get it confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

You can break genome string into parts and search for substrings simultaneously using multiprocessing to minimize the single processor usage and faster results.

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Pool

def SplitGenomeString(start,length):
#where con in sqlconnection to database using as global variable
   cursorObj = con.cursor()


   cursorObj.execute('SELECT substr(Chr.Sequence,{},{}) FROM Chromosome 
                      Chr'.format(str(start),str(length))
   return cursorObj.fetchall()

def getSubSequence(s):
#Write your Queries according to your requirements for finding subsequence s




if __name__ == '__main__':
    length = SplitGenomeString(0,sys.maxint)
    cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()

    #asumming the subsequence you want to check is 100
    subseq_len = 100

    for i in range(0,length,round(length/cores)):
        ls.append(SplitGenomeString(i,round(length/cores)))

    #this will also include the excluded parts because of splitting geneome string
    temp = []
    for i in range(len(ls) - 1):
        temp.append(ls[i][1 - subseq_len):] + ls[i+1][:subseq_len - 1])

    ls = ls + temp

    with Pool(cores) as p:
        p.map(getSubSequence,ls)
```

You can see about multiprocessing in this link:
 https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

**Edited as told**

Comment: And what if a sequence spans where you have split the genome? It looks like your code posted with some indentation problems btw.

Comment: Yeah it may be possible, then you have to check by joining them, I am splitting genome by default cpu cores count but it should be splitted according to the length of substring you want to check.

Comment: Suppose you want to split the genomes in four parts then you have to check for 4+3 parts by multiprocessor where the 3 parts are the part of previous splited genome which is the size of substring from end part - 1 and the part of next splited genome which is the size of substring from beginning - 1. I will edit the code soon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1, however then I prefer to do it with the fasta index approach.